# validar números de teléfono únicos en la dirección de facturación de woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress

Uso este código pero al revisar aparece internal server error

```
add_filter( 'update_user_meta', 'ts_unique_wc_phone_field');
function ts_unique_wc_phone_field( $errors ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        $hasPhoneNumber = get_users('meta_value='.$_POST['billing_phone']);
        if ( !empty($hasPhoneNumber)) {
            $errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Mobile number is already used!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

---

Comment: no puedo comentar porque soy nuevo, pero mira esta pagina ya habían echo algo similar a ver si te sirve https://hi.coredump.biz/questions/59948508/how-to-make-customer-billing-phone-number-unique-in-wordpress#59961382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solución: tenía un plugin para sólamente dejar campos personalizados (checkout field editor), al activar el teléfono y hacer el paso anterior internamente no lo reconocía por el plugin, lo que hice es volver a registrarlo con el siguiente código.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-customer-billing-phone-number-unique-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You creo que tu implementación de la función `get_users()` es incorrecta. Intenta usándola de esta manera:

```
$hasPhoneNumber = get_users( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'billing_phone',
            'value' => $_POST['billing_phone']
        )
    )
) );
```

Referencia: [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)

Comment: muchas gracias, agregue las lineas de código y remplacé lo anterior,, Sigue apareciendo el mensaje "Internal server error".

Comment: Tienes un error en otro lado. Edita **wp-config.php** y cambia el valor de **WP_DEBUG** de esta manera: `define('WP_DEBUG, true);` . Si es un error de sintaxis y tienes deshabilitado "display_errors", vas a tener que revisar el log de errores de Apache/PHP.